# Phonegap App crashes unexpectedly on startup after update from 1.4.1 to 1.9.0

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I just excavated a maybe 3 months old Phonegap (for Android) project from my archives. Since I always had little problems with the sound API (sounds playing twice or not stopping - the rest was working just fine) I thought it might be a good idea to update to the latest version of Phonegap / now Cordova, which currently is 1.9.0. Unfortunately the app now crashes on startup (telling me it was forced to stop unexpectedly in an alert box) in all devices that I can test on (virtual and real handsets).

I guess I might have forgotten something in the update process so I'll just list what I actually did during the update:

- replaced the JAR file to 1.9.0
- replaced the JS library to 1.9.0 (and replaced the reference in the `index.html`
- Edited my `AndroidManifest.xml` to match **[this page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)**
- Replaced the `plugins.xml` content with the new version
- Replaced the `phonegap.xml` in the `res`folder by the new `cordova.xml`
- changed the imports in the main `AppActivity.java` file
- Updated the all the SDK packages in Eclipse

Somehow this doesn't seem to suffice.

Did I just miss something that still needs to be done or is this some problem with something that I am doing inside my app? I didn't use any Cordova API except for playing Sounds.

`minSdkVersion` is 8 by the way.

Comment: Error logs might have the answer you are looking for... If you can Post that then i will tell u the answer :)

Comment: @Coder_sLaY Error logs do not (did not) throw any errors unfortunately :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what did the trick (kind of) for me was to create a new Project in Eclipse, set it up the exact same way and just incorporate my `www` folder into the new project.

The two projects look exactly the same but lord only knows that I probably have missed something. In case anyone still has input on this, don't hesitate to share it!